# How to change AppId in Visual Studio for Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I created a Xamarin Forms app and want to run the app on my iPhone. It already runs nicely in the simulator. To get it on the phone, I created an ad-hoc provisioning profile for de.mycompany.* . In Visual Studio I set the Bundle Identifier to de.mycompany.appname . I also in Visual Studio preferences went to Apple Developer Accounts. And hit the "Download all profiles" button.

Still, when I try to compile I get the error

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(3,3):
>   Error: No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS
>   signing identities. (ApplicationName.iOS)

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me updating to Version 7.1 (build 1297) of Visual Studio fixed the problem. I had to enter the team info again but then it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

The bundle identifier is defined in Info.plist. Open that file and change it.

If you are opening the file as XML then the section will look like:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>my.app.identifier</string>
```

Just change the contents in between the two `string` tags.

Otherwise in the plist editor it will look like:

[image]

If you still have the error where it fails to find a matching provisioning profile. Make sure that you have downloaded and installed the provisioning profiles through Xcode.

This can be done in Xcode. Pressing the Xcode menu in the top:

> Preferences -> Accounts -> Select your account -> Download All Provisioning Profiles

If you are trying to build for release make sure you have your signing identity installed on the machine as well.

Comment: Thank you @Cheesbaron . Have done all that and I can deploy an App from Xcode but NOT from Visual Studio. I put build output to verbose and that's what I get:

Target _DetectSigningIdentity:
    DetectSigningIdentity Task
      AppBundleName: Appname.iOS
      AppManifest: Info.plist
      Keychain: <null>
      ProvisioningProfile: <null>
      RequireCodesigning: True
      RequireProvisioningProfile: True
      SdkPlatform: iPhoneOS
      SdkIsSimulator: False
      SigningKey: iPhone Developer

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(605,3): error : No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS signing identities.

Comment: Dunno, I can't reproduce your issue from my end. I think it is best you contact Xamarin to get help from one of their engineers.

Comment: Have you added your device UDID in the Apple Developer Center, added it to a provisioning profile and downloaded the profile?